# HTML 5 pattern allow numeric values 4 characters max plus dash plus numeric character 11 characters max?

Tags: regex, html

I have input field that should accept only this format: `number (4 characters max) - number (11 characters max)`. I have this patter but that will not force user to enter the number in format like this for example: `3453-24`

Here is the code:

```
<input type="text" name="search_value" id="search_value" placeholder="Example: 0421-055" pattern="[0-9]+([-][0-9]+)?" title="ID allows dash and numeric characters only" maxlength="12" required="required">
```

Is there a way to validate this kind of input with pattern regex?

Comment: Do you mean like `\d{1,4}-\d{1,11}`

Comment: Probably, `pattern="\d{1,4}(?:-\d{1,11})?"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this pattern:

```
pattern="[0-9]{1,4}-[0-9]{1,11}"
```

### Demo

This would allow as few as one digit one each side of the hyphen, and as many as 4 on the LHS or 11 on the RHS.